# Inheritance Costs in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

Taking the following snippet as an example:

```
struct Foo
{
  typedef int type;
};

class Bar : private Foo
{
};

class Baz
{
};
```

As you can see, no virtual functions exist in this relationship. Since this is the case, are the the following assumptions accurate as far as the language is concerned?

- No virtual function table will be created in `Bar`.
- `sizeof(Bar) == sizeof(Baz)`

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if I'll be paying any sort of penalty for doing this. My initial testing (albeit on a single compiler) indicates that my assertions are valid, but I'm not sure if this is my compiler's optimizer or the language specification that's responsible for what I'm seeing.

Comment: +1 for your curiosity and inquisitiveness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the standard, Bar is not a POD (plain old data) type, because it has a base. As a result, the standard gives C++ compilers wide latitude with what they do with such a type.

However, very few compilers are going to do anything insane here. The one thing you probably have to look out for is the Empty Base Optimization. For various technical reasons, the C++ standard requires that any instance be allocated storage space. For some compilers, Foo will be allocated dedicated space in the `bar` class. Compilers which implement the Empty Base Optimization (most all in modern use) will remove the empty base, however.

If the given compiler does not implement EBO, then `sizeof(foo)` will be at least twice `sizeof(baz)`.

Comment: is there a way to turn off EBO ?

Comment: @Gollum: Sure, two ways. 1. Consult your compilers' documentation to see if they provide such an option. 2. Make the base non-empty. Stick an unused `char` or `int` in there :)

Comment: Superb. Thanks for bringing my attention to EBO. :)

Comment: `EBO` is worth knowing: it's the only valid justification for using `private` inheritance instead of composition :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, without any virtual members or member variables, there shouldn't be a size difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the compiler will optimize this correctly, if any optimizing is needed at all.